# SVG types support in Flow.js?

Tags: reactjs, dom, svg, flowtype

I've looked around at various [github thread](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/4551)s and it seems as if SVG support is not merged / shipped in current versions of Flow.js (I'm using VS Code extension `vscode-flow-ide`). I'm trying to work with SVG refs and for now have had to use a mix of less-specific type (`Element`) and `// $FlowFixMe` to work around these - not ideal from a broader type-safety perspective.

Anyone solved this? I'm using `/flow/lib/dom.js` currently, but it lacks these types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interrim solution [until the official inclusions are made](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/4551#issuecomment-570667660)...

For types that are missing, implement your own for that subset of properties that you intend to use.

For example, I am manipulating SVGs, so in a file `SVGElement.js.flow` (named after the [DOM type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement)):

```
type SVGElement = HTMLElement & 
{
    fonts: [],
    fillOpacity: number
    //...
    //In reality, SVGElement has many more properties, but you can include  
    //only those you will use and which thus require type-safety.
    //You can add whatever you need, incrementally, as time passes.
}
```

Typing only subsets of methods & properties is easier than having to implement the entire type.

The `&` allows inheritance from `HTMLElement` present in `/flow/lib/dom.js`; see [intersection types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/).